# Using a generator in a Requests-based script

Tags: python, python-requests, generator

I have a list of URLs (stored in a csv file) output from my network mapping software.  The script below feeds the URLs into a "Get" request so that I can retrieve the data (network device configuration) and save it to a json file.

```
import json, csv
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

device_url = []
device_details = []

with open('dev_locations.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        device_url.append(row['URL'])

headers = {'accept' : 'application/json'}
login = HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'password')

for t in device_url:
    s = requests.Session()
    response = s.get(t, verify=False, auth=login, headers=headers)
    nice_work = (response.json())
    device_details.append(nice_work)
    with open('device_details.json', 'w') as out_file:
        json.dump(device_details, out_file, indent=3)
```

I have another version of this script that saves the output to XML instead of json.  They both work well.

My issue is that the scripts take more than 24 hours to finish.  I was researching ways to make Python scripts faster and I came across generators, but I have no idea how I could write one that fits into this script or if it is even possible to use one to speed things up in this scenario.

I haven't had any issues with my code...it just takes forever to create the output file.

Comment: I don't think generators would help here. Maybe what you are looking for is asynchronous requests. Essentially, you would not wait for a respond to send a new request, which is what is happening now

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into asynchronous requests as pointed out by @Yiannis, a good library for this is aiohttp. Make sure to have asyncio and aiohttp installed to use it.

https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp

Comment: Will do.  I definitely didn't consider those modules.  Cheers.